# Is there a way to input multiple parameters into a method via an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, parameters

Say I have a method that needs three arguments:

```
def foo(a, b, c)
end
```

And I have said arguments in an array:

```
[a, b, c]
```

Is there a trivial or one method way of using the array as the arguments, like:

```
foo(array.some_method)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [splat operator](http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/):

```
foo(*array)
```

Comment: Does the splat operator have to be in the method's definition? I am trying to use a library class method, so I can't alter the signature of the method.

Comment: No, it's a way of 'exploding' an array to match an existing method signature, so in your example you can use it without altering your `foo` method

Comment: You're right. Although the code that results its fairly funkified: `Date.valid_date?(*'9666-96-96'.split('-').map(&:to_i))`. I probably should make it into two steps.

Comment: Looks indeed like an ugly oneliner :)

Answer (score 4):

```
def foo(*bar)

end
```

Foo now exacts an array as parameters. You could also make it accept a hash by doing

```
def foo(bar={})

end
```